# Validate LHS+OPERATOR+RHS regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation

I have only  these operators : `>`,`>=`,`<`,`<=`,`==`,`!=`,`matches`

I have some values like below and expected Result

```
<1.1> == 10                 Match
<1.1> != 10                 Match
<1.1> matches test          Match
<1.1> matches test|user     Match
<1.1> matches 10            Match
<1.1> matches 10|20         Match

<1.1> >= 10|20              Don't Match
<1.1> == 10|20              Don't Match
<1.1> != test               Don't Match
<1.1> == test               Don't Match
```

I tried this

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.<>]+[\s](<|<=|>|>=|==|!=|matches)[\s][a-zA-Z0-9_.<>|]+$/
```

but not working.

Comment: You should tell use *why* results should match or not

Comment: matches only allow alpha. opr needs to allow integers

Comment: Could you rephrase your comment? I don't understand...

Comment: I want to compare rhs side using matches only allow alphanumeric with underscore,pipe and dot characters. Another case is >,>=,<,<=,==,!= only compare numeric values only. If operator "matches" then RHS is alphanumeric with underscore,pipe and dot characters then numeric

Comment: put this in the edition of your post

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.<>]+\s(?:(?:<|<=|>|>=|==|!=)\s\d+|matches\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.<>|]+)$/gm
```

I've added an alternation to separate matches from the others operators. You can see a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/rD3yH3/1)

Comment: thanks.. its working. but i have checked some more cases its not working <1.1> == <1.1>,<1.1> >= <test> this is valid but it says invalid.

Comment: @user3265033 because `<1,1>` is not numerics only